# Entity Framework Query select hard-coded user created column

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm creating a select from multiple tables using a union as I need to return a list of activities that has occurred for a particular client on the database. I need to return each union with an added column so I can tell the difference between the results.  If I was to do the query in SQL it would look something like this:

SELECT cn.NoteID, cn.Note, cn.InsertedDate, 'Note Added' Notes

FROM Client c

INNER JOIN ClientNotes cn ON cn.ClientID = c.ID

WHERE c.ClientID = @ClientID

UNION

SELECT rc.ID, rc.CommNote, rc.InsertedDate, 'Communication Added' Notes

FROM ReceivedCommunication rc

LEFT JOIN Job j ON j.ID = rc.JobID

WHERE j.ClientID =  @ClientID or rc.ClientID = @ClientID

**My Question is** how in Entity Framework using IQuerable do I return the hard-coded Notes column?
I have something like this so far:

Dim client as IQueryable(Of myresultclass) = 
(From c As Client

Join cn As ClientNotes In ClientCompanyNotes On c.ID Equals cn.ClientID

Where c.ClientID = ClientID

Select cn.NoteID, cn.Note, cn.InsertedDate).Union(

From rc As ReceivedCommunication In ReceivedCommunications

Join j As Job In Jobs On j.ID Equals rc.JobID

Where j.ClientID =  ClientID or rc.ClientID = ClientID

Select rc.ID, rc.CommNote, rc.InsertedDate)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok worked it out, should have been obvious.  For anyone with the same issue, I had to update my Select from Select cn.NoteID, cn.Note, cn.InsertedDate to:

```
Select New myresultclass With {
    .ActivityID = cn.NoteID,
    .ActivityType = "Note Added"
    .InsertedDate = cn.InsertedDate
}
```

for each one of the unions that I had

Thanks